# Future await not waiting

Tags: flutter, dart

the `sortHabitsList()` method executes before `loadHabitsSortOrder()` can complete.

```dart
() async {
  debugPrint('Habits Sort order Changed, Fetching Sort order');
  await loadHabitsSortOrder();
  sortHabitsList();
}
```

Following is the loadHabitsSortOrder() method:

```dart
Future<void> loadHabitsSortOrder() async {
    Either<Failure, dynamic> response =
        await miscRepository.getItem(AppStrings.sortOrderMapKey);

    response.fold( <- Stops at this line
      (failure) => DialogHelper.showErrorDialog(failure),
      (sortingOrder) {
        if (sortingOrder != null) {
          currentSortOrder = sortingOrder['sortOrder'];
          sortedHabitIds = sortingOrder['sortedHabitIds'];
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I used breakpoints to check what was happening. In the `loadHabitsSortOrder()` method, it stops at `response.fold(` line and jumps directly to the `sortHabitsList()`.

After completing the `sortHabitsList()` method the remaining code in the `loadHabitsSortOrder()` gets completed. That is from `response.fold(` line

Why is this happening? Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example?

Comment: can you explain where is the first async function is placed